# How to write into a table with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, getelementbyid

```
<Script>
function getExperience()
{
    var xp = document.getElementById('txt_XP').value;
    document.getElementByID("plank").innerHTML = xp/30;
}
</Script>
```

So here is my code, and my problem is that I seem to be unable to write over data in a table with the id's planl, oakPlank, teakPlank, and mahoganyPlank. I am thinking that I may be making an obvious mistake to someone who has done this sort of thing before, but I can't seem to catch it. Any help is much appreciated, and here is a snippet of my table, if it helps:

```
<tr>
    <td>Plank</td>
    <td id="plankXP">30</td>
    <td id="plank">0</td>
</tr>
```

EDIT: I didn't realize that this may be pertinent, my bad. This is the form I used to get input, which after putting an alert in to see if it could retrieve the XP, it functioned correctly:

```
<form name="experience" id="experience_frm" action="#">
    Experience: <input type="text" name="XP" id="txt_XP"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" onclick="getExperience();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you mean `plankXP` where you wrote `txt_XP`?

Comment: try putting alert in `getExperience()`, is it firing properly?

Comment: @MattBall I wouldn't think so. They seem to understand the difference between `.value` and `.innerHTML`, and even have the `id` including "txt"...so I'm guessing it's a textbox we haven't been shown.

Comment: I've made sure that getExperience is firing properly, the only problem is it won't seem to write over the 0 that I left as a placeholder in the third cell of that row. @ITppl

Comment: Are these rows (and `id`s) duplicated?

Comment: @Ian, yes, I apologize. The code I used will be up in a sec for the form

Comment: Each id/row is unique to the file also @Ian

Comment: Can it be that when you click on the button your page is refreshed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used the wrong `document` method. Javascript is case sensitive. You used:

```
document.getElementByID
```

for getting the `id="plank"` element. But you need to use:

```
document.getElementById
```

Notice the `d` (last character) change.

With this change, a simple example works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/wqZAq/

Comment: Oh gosh. Thank you for that, I knew it had to be something small, I was just staring at it for the past hour and at that point I needed a second opinion. Awesome help.

Comment: @zsherman Haha no problem. These little typos are the worst thing too, and so hard to notice. Something that might've helped, is if you had your browser's console open, you should've gotten an exception, and would've at least helped narrow down what the problem could've been.

Comment: @zsherman Yeah, an IDE could help with autocomplete, but the browser's console will provide runtime exceptions and problems, and allow you to monitor some things. They're normally activated by pressing F12 (if it comes native), but could require downloading. In Firefox, it's Firebug (an addon). In Internet Explorer and Chrome, it's Developer Tools (same name, different things)

Comment: One follow-up question if any of you have time; what is causing the page to refresh after getExperience() fires?

Comment: @zsherman Your calling `getExperience` from a **submit** button. It's submitting the form!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<Script>
function getExperience()
{
    var xp = document.getElementById('txt_XP').value;
    var newxp = parseInt(xp);
    var div = newxp/30;
    document.getElementById("plank").innerHTML = div;
}
</Script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Plank</td>
    <td id="plankXP">30</td>
    <td id="plank">0</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="txt_XP" name="txt_XP" />
<input type="button" onclick="getExperience();" />
```